# Scrolling in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-scrollbar

For me, scrolling in flutter is not working, So I wrote a simple test code as below to show the problem, how can I make this content to scroll? Can someone help.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestScreenExtends extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestScreenExtends({super.key});

  Widget getRow(int rowId, int count) {
    List<Widget> widgets = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      widgets.add(Text("rowitem ($rowId, $i) "));
    }
    return Row(
      children: widgets,
    );
  }

  Widget getRows(int count) {
    List<Widget> rows = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      rows.add(getRow(i, 20));
    }
    return Column(
      children: rows,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(Object context) {
    return Material(
      child: getRows(50),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Scrolling does not appear]

---

Edit-2
Problem can be demonstrated in even smaller code. Vertical listview has scrollbar, Horizontal view is not getting it.see below code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestScreenExtends extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestScreenExtends({super.key});

  Widget getRow(int rowId, int count) {
    List<Widget> widgets = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      widgets.add(SizedBox(
          width: 80,
          child: Text(
            "item($rowId, $i)",
            softWrap: false,
          )));
    }
    return ListView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      //scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      children: widgets,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(Object context) {
    return Material(
      child: getRow(1, 50),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Check this widget - https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html

Comment: Needed both vertical and horizontal scrolling. The horizontal scrolling is not working.

Answer (score 1):

First wrap your `getRows(1000)` with SingleChildScrollView for vertival overflow issue, then wrap your `text` with `Expanded` for horizontal overflow issue, like this:

```
class TestScreenExtends extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestScreenExtends({super.key});

  Widget getRow(int rowId, int count) {
    List<Widget> widgets = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      widgets.add(SizedBox(
          width: 80,
          child: Text(
            "item($rowId, $i)",
            softWrap: false,
          )));
    }
    return Row(
      children: widgets,
    );
  }

  Widget getRows(int count) {
    List<Widget> rows = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      rows.add(getRow(i, 10));
    }
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: Column(
        children: rows,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(Object context) {
    return Material(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        child: getRows(100),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This fixes the vertical scroll issue, but it won't fix the horizontal scroll issue. It just alleviate the problem by wrapping. Horizontal scrollbar is still not coming. It will truncate the texts if we make _softWrap=false_ in the Text. In my real scenario, the text boxes are inside _SizedBox_'s to make a table kind of display. The real question is how we can have both vertical and horizontal scrollbars to display the content.

Comment: oo, now I understand that, your main question wasn't clear. let me some time to fix it.

Comment: still horizontal scroll is not working

Comment: Its worked but because the list in horizontal way is small you have to try it in small width screen , and also it is very laggy in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your widget in a  SingleChildScrollView :

```
 SingleChildScrollView(
      child: getRows(50))
```

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html

This is very beginner stuff that are **explained** in the flutter get started, you should really dig deeper and understand the fundamentals of Flutter, Widget and how the UI Is built otherwise you will face many issues and bug.

Flutter has an amazing documentation and tutorials, do use the [Code Lab](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/codelab)

Comment: Got the same suggestion from many, but that fixes only vertical scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

use scroll for horizontal view

```
return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
       child:Column(
          children: rows,
         )
      );
```

use scroll for vertical view

```
return SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
           child:Column(
              children: rows,
             )
          );
```

and u you can use separate scroll in all view

```
ingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,// Axis.horizontal,
child: widget
)
```

Comment: horizontal scroll did not work, I updated the question with new code which contains two SingleChildScrollView's.